what does."ガチャ大ハズレ" mean?
i saw that word in comment by someone talking about a person who was being/sitting next to them " 新幹線、隣の人ガチャ大ハズレでした"

We don't do translations.

Sosos, your question is interesting, but next time, please read the link above before asking questions, and share the research you've done. Since this is a site where humans take time to answer questions, we have this rule as a minimal requirement.


新幹線、隣の人ガチャ(は)大【おお】ハズレでした。
On the shinkansen, my "seatmate lootbox" was a total fail.
(i.e., I got an unpleasant seatmate.)


ガチャ is gacha/lootbox. Here, 隣の人ガチャ is being used as a humorous noun phrase. This type of ～ガチャ is internet slang that has become widespread in recent years, referring to a situation where you have no control over what you get. The best-known example is 親ガチャ.
ハズレ (外れ in kanji) is the antonym of 当たり (hit/win). 大 is an intensifier ("total", "complete", etc).

